# Create a folder on desktop

Tags: vb.net

I want to create a folder on the desktop and I want to create it once. However, once my project is installed, when I debug my program I get this error:

> Conversion from string to " gfgffgfgfg " type integer is not valid

Here is my code:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Try
        MkDir(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop("gfgffgfgfg"))

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
    End Try
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what passing the string to `Desktop` is meant to do, and I'd expect other forms of compile errors (though I don't know the VB compiler very well), but maybe you want this:

```
Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop, "gfgffgfgfg")
```

That should return the fully-qualified path for the folder being created.

Comment: @MayaShb: There's a `Directory.Exists` method for testing that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists.aspx

Comment: @MayaShb: Verify the answer as correct(Tick it green), if it was useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Dim SELEXPED_DIR As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop + "\SELEXPED"

    If Directory.Exists(SELEXPED_DIR) = False Then
        Try
            Directory.CreateDirectory(SELEXPED_DIR)

        Catch ex As Exception
            'Nothing to do
        End Try
    End If
```

Comment: Please add some explanation.